# renderPDF breaks in Windows 10

Tags: python, svg, reportlab

I recently migrated my Python code to my new Windows 10 laptop with Python.

I notice that my Python code that renders multiple SVG images into a PDF file using reportlab renderPDF and svg2rlg are now broken. My rendered images in the PDF are now coming out in black and white and very poor quality. The code illustrated worked fine before migrating to Windows 10. Any ideas appreciated.

I do not think I missed any Python libraries. This same code works fine in Linux.

```
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
#
strMyTestSVGFile = "test.svg"
my_canvas = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf")
#
drawing = svg2rlg(strMyTestSVGFile)
#
renderPDF.draw(drawing, my_canvas, 0,0)
my_canvas.save()
```

This is just a code snippet. This used to work great. My color SVG graphs from R could be grouped with Python into a nice PDF report. I need the vector graphics to keep the clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I downgraded to svglib 0.8.1 from 0.9.0 and everything is good now. Posted a bug report to the svglib author.

Comment: I come back to this answer every time I reinstall Python and run my scripts.